# How do I ensure my POST request was successful? Can anybody approve my code below?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send a POST request to send JSON to elastic Search.
Below is my .razor file,
Demos() is a method that is called upon a button click :

I referred to this https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/sending-and-receiving-json-using-httpclient-with-system-net-http-json for the code below. However ay other method of POST would be appreciated as well. Thanks

```
@code {

@using System.Net.Http;
@using System.IO;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
@using System.Text;
@using System.Web;
@using System.Net.Http.Json; //dotnet add package System.Net.Http.Json --version 3.2.0-preview3.20175.8 (in command line to install)

private void Demos()
{
    static async Task PostJsonHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
         // read JSON directly from a file
        JObject o3;
        using (StreamReader file = File.OpenText(@"example.json"))
        using (JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(file))
        {
            o3 = (JObject)JToken.ReadFrom(reader);
        }


        var postResponse = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost:9200/xo-triggertypes/_doc/",o3);

        postResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: You are only extracting data from the httpbody, which has nothing to do with the security you want. If you must protect the data, you can use SHA encryption before data transmission.

Comment: What is the actual question? Code reviews should go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com